# Building using Jenkins and CocoaPods - 'Update CocoaPods' marked build as failure

Tags: shell, jenkins, cocoapods

I'm working on a Unity game that's to be exported as an iOS project and built with Xcode. We've got an existing Jenkins setup that does the job for me at a click of a button, but recently I've been asked to add WebTrends to my project.

The manual process for that is as follows:

- Copy over a podfile, a pre-made webtrends.plist file, and the pods folder (so I don't have to download that over again).
- Do a `pod install` on the project directory.
- Open xcworkspace file and build as normal.

So I went to Jenkins Plugin Manager, and installed (without restarting) CocoaPods Jenkins Integration. This, however, unhelpfully added a Build Step called Update CocoaPods. Upon adding that to my Build Steps and running it, it resulted in the following:

```
[workspace] $ pod repo update
Build step 'Update CocoaPods' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

The documentation wasn't very helpful either, only saying that, currently, this has no advantage over running an execute shell script. So I did just that, and added a `pod install` to the Build Step, which resulted in the following:

```
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/afesefgwedc.sh: line 26: pod: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

So clearly pod was not installed. I don't have the credentials or the rights to install it myself, I would have thought installing CocoaPods via Jenkins would have done it. And even if I did, there's that previous error to contend with. I could try to reboot the server, but that's a last resort.

Has anyone successfully integrated pods with Jenkins? What else could I try, or what else did I miss?

I'm quite new at Jenkins, so I apologize in advance if this seems lacking. I would be happy to provide other information if requested.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install pod , you need to write following command in **Execute shell** of **Build** phase.

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

Because for installing pod, you need to give path for executable pod file. And with above command in execute shell helping you for install the pod.

*Note - Jenkins looked in a workspace whether pod is installed or not. If there is already installed pod on your workspace, jenkins not installed it again. And if not then it installing pod.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you have cocoapods installed, try this:
`which pod`

Which will display where's the pod command located:
`/Users/HomeDir/.rbenv/shims/pod`